# Building exported Eclipse project in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I used the Eclipse export to "Generate Cradle build Files" so that my Eclipse project for my android app could be compiled and edited in Android Studio. (I used the 6.4 commonsware instructions on pp866).

But when I try to build the module I get the following Gradle build error ...

A problem occurred configuring project ':com.deanblakely.mttTrial'.
"> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable."

However my local.properties has . . .
sdk.dir=C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Android\sdk  which is the correct location for the sdk

Also the project Location is correctly set . . .
[image]

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

The build.gradel generated for the module. . .

```
> apply plugin: 'android' dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>     compile project(':library')
>     compile project(':google-play-services_lib') } android {
>     compileSdkVersion 21
>     buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>     }
>     sourceSets {
>         main {
>             manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
>             java.srcDirs = ['src']
>             resources.srcDirs = ['src']
>             aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
>             renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
>             res.srcDirs = ['res']
>             assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
>         }
>         // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
>         instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
>         // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
>         // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
>         // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
>         // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
>         // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
>         // by a similar customization.
>         debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
>         release.setRoot('build-types/release')
>     } }
```

This build.gradle was added to the root of my workspace . . .

```
> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
> to all sub-projects/modules. buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
>     } }
```

The export process also generated two build.gradles for both of the library project I use.
I have SDK tools 24.0.2 installed
I have SDK Platform-tools 21 installed
I have SDK Build-tools 21.1.2 installed.
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Go into File > Project Structure in Android Studio, and see what is filled in the "Android SDK location" field.

Comment: I edited the project to show that the Project Location also appears to be correctly set. :(